# jquery.validator errorPlacement with jquery.gritter

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, javascript-objects

I'm trying to use jQuery.Gritter within jQuery.validator's errorPlacement... as to send the form validation error to a fancy little container.  seems simple enough.  maybe i'm just not familiar enough with OOP.. heh.

```
    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {          
        $.gritter.add({
            title: 'Whoops!',
            text: error,
            image: '/global/media/formExcl.png',
            sticky: false,
            time: ''
        });
   },
```

So... 'error' is an object... so this is obviously gonna produce '[object Object]'.  I've done a little bit of searching trying to get the essence out of the object.

I tried 'error.toSource()' to produce a breakdown of the object.. hoping to get the property name that holds the error value... but I just get this.. '({0:({}), length:1})'.

'error.['0']' or error.[0] doesnt fly for syntax.

help a noob out.

Answer (score 0):

`error` is a dom element try this.

```
errorPlacement: function(error, element) {          
        $.gritter.add({
            title: 'Whoops!',
            text: $(error).text(),
            image: '/global/media/formExcl.png',
            sticky: false,
            time: ''
        });
   },
```

Comment: No that doesn't work.  Maybe I've miscommunicated what I'm trying to accomplish.  'error' is an object created by jQuery.validate... not a form input.  Within the 'error' object there is a property that holds a value of something like "please enter a valid email address."  I'm trying to extract that string and hand it over to the 'text' property of the gritter.add method.

Comment: I have used it, and `error` is a dom element believe me. Take a look at this http://jsfiddle.net/Ax7Bs/2/. Did you try it?

Comment: The fiddle I provided is one of my answer to question on SO.

Comment: I used object iteration to find that 'error' is a multi dimensional object... found the object 'textContent' 2 objects in.  Thanks for your efforts.

Comment: error[0].innerText does the trick, however as I have discovered the error placement is triggered on every click after its initial trigger.  This may result in many unwanted gritter messages for the same error.